# Wordpress !Doctype Halting up my flash liquid layout

Tags: html, css, flash, doctype

I'm building wordpress blog themed in flash and I've already run into one problem.

this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Will not let me scale my .swf to 100% width and 100% height.  Width is fine, but the height is not.

my css is as follows:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#flashcontent {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

the object and embed tags are also both set to 100% by 100%.

Here are two screen shots.  One [with the doctype](http://www.hupcapstudios.com/resources/withDoc.png)

And one [without](http://www.hupcapstudios.com/resources/withoutDoc.png)

I don't want to ditch it, as I know that's bad practice.  Any suggestions on which type I should use?  From what I can recall, 100% height is outmoded?  Any suggestions/input greatly appreciated.

-J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try {top:0; bottom:0;}

Comment: You could try being the most awesome answerer ever.  Worked perfect, thanks!